# is it possible to make dual y axis graph using angular google chart

Tags: angularjs, charts, google-visualization

how to make dual y axis chart using google chart in angular js?

could you please any one help me out how to make it?

like : [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaEjw.png)

[image]

```
  $scope.myChartObject1 = {};

         $scope.myChartObject1.type = "ColumnChart";


          $scope.myChartObject1.data =   ['Galaxy', 'Distance', 'Brightness'],
          ['Canis Major Dwarf', 8000, 23.3],
          ['Sagittarius Dwarf', 24000, 4.5],
          ['Ursa Major II Dwarf', 30000, 14.3],
          ['Lg. Magellanic Cloud', 50000, 0.9],
          ['Bootes I', 60000, 13.1];


 <div google-chart chart="myChartObject"  on-select="getTheValue(selectedItem)" style="height:421px; width:100%;"></div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: where do you define the chart options? -- you would set `targetAxisIndex` for the `series` in your [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The google documentation shows examples with the new Material Charts instead of the older chart classes. With the older charts (`ColumnChart`, `BarChart`), use something like this:

```
$scope.chartObject.options = {
  vAxes: {
    0: {title: "Inventory"},
    1: {title: "Sales" }
  },
  series: {
     0: {targetAxisIndex: 0},
     1: {targetAxisIndex: 1}
  }
 };
```

I also have a [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/nbering/pen/yNZxKr) that was meant for image overlays, but it also happens to use Dual-Y options.